# Solving combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

$X$ is a finite set with the following property:
The number of subsets of $X$ that contain exactly $3$ elements is $14$ more than number of subsets of $X$ that contain exactly 2 elements. How many subsets of $X $ contain exactly one element?

Honestly I have no idea about combinatorics. Need to solve this urgently too.

Comment: Why is this so urgent?

Comment: "Need to solve this urgently". Wish you are not in an ongoing test... Understand that we do not work in a hurry...

Comment: I have the whole day though. Just want to get it earlier. Its an exams preparation question that just popped up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to solve $\binom n3-\binom n2=14$, which can be rewritten as
$$\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}6-\frac{n(n-1)}2=14$$
$$n(n-1)(n-5)=84$$
By inspection we see that $n=7$ satisfies this equation, as well as the original. So $|X|=7$, which is also the number of $1$-element subsets as $\binom n1=n=7$.

Comment: Thanks man. Really grateful.